# Go fmt float64 issue

Tags: go, gofmt

I've come across a bit of a gotcha in my noob understanding of go fmt package

It relates to the following code:

import "fmt"

```
func main() {
    var smallFloat float64 = 0.123456789
    var bigFloat float64 = 123456789000

    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%f", smallFloat))
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%f", bigFloat))
}
```

The output is:

```
0.123457
123456789000.000000
```

I don't want to use scientific notation so thought %f would suit my needs.I can see from the formatting page (https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) it says:

```
The default precision for %e and %f is 6; for %g it is the smallest number of digits necessary to identify the value uniquely.
```

Is there a way I can use the fmt package that would allow me represent the full decimal value of smallFloat while at the same time not appending 6 zeros to the end of bigFloat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`strconv.FormatFloat`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatFloat) with prec set to -1:

```
fmt.Println(strconv.FormatFloat(big, 'f', -1, 64))
fmt.Println(strconv.FormatFloat(small, 'f', -1, 64))
```

prints

```
123456789000
0.123456789
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/7p8xnQ_BzE.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for your help. I was looking in the wrong package :D

Comment: @Airomega No problem. Honestly, I'm kinda surprised there seems to be no way of getting this result with `fmt`.